# Maven-gae-plugin 0.9.4: no version available for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar-- Help me explain the solution of the bug

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, maven-gae-plugin

This bug was closed on github, 
https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin/issues/39
however i don't understand its fixing, and when i execute gae goal such as mvn gae:update it always gives me the same problem. could anyone explain the root cause of this problem based on its fixing?

For your info, i copy-paste the original problem and its fixing here:

> > From this morning I continue to get this error:
>
> Failed to execute goal net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.4:unpack
>   (execution2) on project gui: Execution execution2 of goal
>   net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.4:unpack failed: Plugin
>   net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:0.9.4 or one of its dependencies could
>   not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for
>   net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin:jar:0.9.4 (): No versions available for
>   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:[1.2,3.0) within specified
>   range
>
> .. and I am stuck with this plugin at the moment!

the fix is:

> .. and I added the "-U" option to the command I use to use: mvn clean
>   verify .. it becomes: mvn -U clean verify

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works for me with `maven-gae-plugin:0.9.4`. Which `gae-runtime` are you targeting?

Comment: i use GAE1.7.1, did you try the mvn gae:update command? did it work? Thanks

Comment: I had this problem, and using mvn gae:update worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it can help someone, here is my solution for the error "No versions available for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:[1.2,3.0)".

I changed the pom configuration for gae-plugin :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.4</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The GAE runtime provided in Maven repos always lags behind official SDK. At the moment official SDK is 1.7.1, but [GAE runtime is only at 1.7.0](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.kindleit%22%20AND%20a%3A%22gae-runtime%22). That's why your unpack command fails - it can't find the version of runtime that you are requesting.

Comment: HI Peter, thanks for your input, Now i rollback to use GAE1.7.0, however when i run mvn -U gae:update-cron it still give me the "No versions available for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:[1.2,3.0) within specified range" error. Any ideas?